# Custom function in nuxt-axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

Is it possible to have a custom function in `nuxt-axios`

```
async fetchSomething({ commit }) {
    const response = await this.$axios.customGet(
      `/blabla`
    );

    await commit("setVideoData", response);
  }
```

And this `customGet()` can have their own `baseUrl` and custom headers

**Edited** to add extra information

This is what i add to `plugins/axios.js` as a try for the `customGet()` function

```
export default function({ $axios, store, redirect }) {
  $axios.customGet(body => {
    console.log("body from custom get", body);
  });
}
```

But is not working and i get this error.

[image]

Comment: It seems that you can indeed extend axios. Have a look at the [documentation](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/extend).

Comment: Hi @mgarcia, thanks for your comment. I try something similar before but don't works, check the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the `TypeError` error because you are calling the function `customGet` (that does not exist) instead of defining it.

Your `plugins/axios.js` should look like:

```
export default function({ $axios, store, redirect }) {
    $axios.customGet = body => {
        /* The logic for customGet goes here */
        console.log("body from custom get", body);
    };
}
```